# AttributeError when trying to save data

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

I am trying to save user input into entry. This is my code:

```
def add(mycontacts):
    name = input('Name: ')
    phone = input('Phone: ')
    email = input('Email: ')

    entry = mycontacts.Contact(name, phone, email)
    if name not in mycontacts:
        mycontacts[name] = entry
        print('The entry has been added.')
    else:
        print('That name already exists.')
```

When I run it, it gices me an error of

```
 entry = mycontacts.Contact(name, phone, email)
 AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Contact'
```

mycontacts is:

```
mycontacts = load_contacts()
```

load_contacts() is

```
def load_contacts():
try:
    input_file = open(FileName, 'rb')
    contact_dct = pickle.load(input_file)
    input_file.close()
except IOError:
    contact_dct = {}

return contact_dct
```

As of right now the value that is held in 'mycontacts' is = {}

Im uncertain on what is making it do this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, what is `mycontacts`?

Comment: I edited the question above to answer your question.

Comment: Next step: remove `try` and `except`. You may find that something does not load.

Comment: Why do you expect `mycontacts.Contact` to be a thing, if `mycontacts` is a dict?

Answer (score 0):

From the error given and your code, "mycontact" is a dictionary and you're explicitly calling an attribute of "Contact" which does not exist. May I suggest you add the values (name, phone, email) to the dictionary "mycontact" before your "if" statement; Like so:

```
mycontacts = {name: name, phone: phone, email:email }
```

or

```
mycontacts[name] = name
mycontacts[phone] = phone
mycontacts[email] = email
```